# Long running process shutting my PC down

Tags: boot, dmesg, 22.10, snap-store, policy

I am using **Ubuntu 22.10** on my **dell laptop [intel i3, amd64]**. First this OS was working fine, but now it is **taking so much time to boot-in**. When I run `sudo dmesg` in terminal, it shows this output:

```
[   97.429059] audit: type=1326 audit(1667911572.579:55): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software pid=1878 comm="snap-store" exe="/snap/snap-store/599/usr/bin/snap-store" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=314 compat=0 ip=0x7fb5932ce73d code=0x50000
[  106.414871] audit: type=1107 audit(1667911581.563:56): pid=706 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.10" pid=1878 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=717 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[  106.415469] audit: type=1107 audit(1667911581.563:57): pid=706 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.10" pid=1878 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=717 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[  106.419575] audit: type=1107 audit(1667911581.567:58): pid=706 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.10" pid=1878 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=717 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[  106.420093] audit: type=1107 audit(1667911581.567:59): pid=706 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.10" pid=1878 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=717 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
```

It is showing that **long running processes of `snap-store` are taking so much time to execute**. It seems that there is any **conflict b/w the policies of snap-store**.

What should I do to solve this problem. If anyone know, please help.

Below is the output of the **`systemd-analyze blame`** command:

```
systemd-analyze blame 

                                                
38.589s plymouth-quit-wait.service
14.386s apport-autoreport.service
13.729s systemd-journal-flush.service
13.271s logrotate.service
12.142s udisks2.service
11.914s snapd.service
 9.932s fwupd.service
 9.538s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 8.956s dev-sda3.device
 7.193s NetworkManager.service
 5.595s accounts-daemon.service
 5.136s dev-loop8.device
 4.957s power-profiles-daemon.service
 4.599s ModemManager.service
 4.027s cups.service
 3.937s polkit.service
 3.774s avahi-daemon.service
 3.267s packagekit.service
 3.224s thermald.service
 3.224s dev-loop1.device
 3.170s snapd.seeded.service
 2.972s grub-common.service
 2.696s bluetooth.service
lines 1-23...skipping...
38.589s plymouth-quit-wait.service
14.386s apport-autoreport.service
13.729s systemd-journal-flush.service
13.271s logrotate.service
12.142s udisks2.service
11.914s snapd.service
 9.932s fwupd.service
 9.538s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 8.956s dev-sda3.device
 7.193s NetworkManager.service
 5.595s accounts-daemon.service
 5.136s dev-loop8.device
 4.957s power-profiles-daemon.service
 4.599s ModemManager.service
 4.027s cups.service
 3.937s polkit.service
 3.774s avahi-daemon.service
 3.267s packagekit.service
 3.224s thermald.service
 3.224s dev-loop1.device
 3.170s snapd.seeded.service
 2.972s grub-common.service
 2.696s bluetooth.service
 2.674s apport.service
 2.667s dbus.service
 2.586s snapd.apparmor.service
 2.508s gpu-manager.service
 2.491s wpa_supplicant.service
 2.440s dev-loop5.device
 2.395s dev-loop0.device
 2.264s switcheroo-control.service
 2.254s systemd-logind.service
 2.208s gdm.service
 2.072s dev-loop6.device
 2.071s colord.service
 2.032s dev-loop2.device
 1.736s dev-loop7.device
 1.621s dev-loop4.device
 1.618s systemd-modules-load.service
 1.545s systemd-udevd.service
38.589s plymouth-quit-wait.service
14.386s apport-autoreport.service
13.729s systemd-journal-flush.service
13.271s logrotate.service
12.142s udisks2.service
11.914s snapd.service
 9.932s fwupd.service
 9.538s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 8.956s dev-sda3.device
 7.193s NetworkManager.service
 5.595s accounts-daemon.service
 5.136s dev-loop8.device
 4.957s power-profiles-daemon.service
 4.599s ModemManager.service
 4.027s cups.service
 3.937s polkit.service
 3.774s avahi-daemon.service
 3.267s packagekit.service
 3.224s thermald.service
 3.224s dev-loop1.device
 3.170s snapd.seeded.service
 2.972s grub-common.service
 2.696s bluetooth.service
 2.674s apport.service
 2.667s dbus.service
 2.586s snapd.apparmor.service
 2.508s gpu-manager.service
 2.491s wpa_supplicant.service
 2.440s dev-loop5.device
 2.395s dev-loop0.device
 2.264s switcheroo-control.service
 2.254s systemd-logind.service
 2.208s gdm.service
 2.072s dev-loop6.device
 2.071s colord.service
 2.032s dev-loop2.device
 1.736s dev-loop7.device
 1.621s dev-loop4.device
 1.618s systemd-modules-load.service
 1.545s systemd-udevd.service
 1.525s update-notifier-download.service
 1.436s systemd-sysusers.service
 1.426s rsyslog.service
 1.322s dev-loop3.device
 1.235s plymouth-start.service
 1.215s grub-initrd-fallback.service
 1.185s systemd-rfkill.service
 1.172s e2scrub_reap.service
 1.081s secureboot-db.service
 1.041s systemd-random-seed.service
 1.038s apparmor.service
  727ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
  717ms keyboard-setup.service
  714ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-8EDB\x2d88BC.service
  712ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
  707ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
  693ms systemd-resolved.service
  616ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
  556ms user@1000.service
  529ms upower.service
  461ms systemd-oomd.service
  447ms kerneloops.service
  411ms snap-snapd\x2ddesktop\x2dintegration-14.mount
  371ms snap-core20-1623.mount
  369ms systemd-timesyncd.service
  359ms snap-core20-1634.mount
  329ms systemd-remount-fs.service
  319ms systemd-sysctl.service
  266ms snap-firefox-1969.mount
  245ms snap-snap\x2dstore-599.mount
  243ms setvtrgb.service
  222ms snap-bare-5.mount
  215ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-119.mount
  206ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1535.mount
  205ms snap-snapd-17336.mount
  195ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-d654630e\x2d9167\x2d4510\x2da658\x2dcd90e3f797f3.swap
  146ms systemd-journald.service
  143ms systemd-timedated.service
  116ms console-setup.service
  115ms plymouth-read-write.service
   95ms boot-efi.mount
   93ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
   91ms openvpn.service
   88ms systemd-update-utmp.service
   87ms rtkit-daemon.service
   70ms modprobe@chromeos_pstore.service
   69ms dev-hugepages.mount
   68ms dev-mqueue.mount
   67ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
   66ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
   60ms kmod-static-nodes.service
   57ms modprobe@configfs.service
   56ms modprobe@drm.service
   53ms modprobe@fuse.service
   45ms systemd-user-sessions.service
   34ms ufw.service
   27ms systemd-backlight@leds:dell::kbd_backlight.service
   19ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
   17ms var-snap-firefox-common-host\x2dhunspell.mount
   13ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
   13ms alsa-restore.service
   11ms modprobe@efi_pstore.service
    9ms modprobe@pstore_blk.service
    6ms modprobe@pstore_zone.service
    6ms modprobe@ramoops.service
    4ms sys-kernel-config.mount
    4ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
    2ms snapd.socket
```

Comment: What's the output of `systemd-analyze blame`?

Comment: Hi @popey I have added the output of the "systemd-analyze blame" command above.

Answer (score 0):

Using the gparted, I found that the root partition has two mounting points as below:

```
Mounted on /, /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
```

and the problem is occuring with the **snap-store**, so to give it a small solution I just removed the **snap-store** from computer which also removed **firefox** (because **firefox** is installed from **snap**) and installed firefox from another platform.

Then did a reboot. Now the problem is solved.